# Build an XML document manually or implement dom interfaces or...?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I process a set of binary files and produce a tree for each file (as they are inherently hierarchical). I would like to use XPath to search and select nodes within the files and would like to not have to write my own XPath engine. XPath queries would be supplied during runtime.

- Does it make sense to try and implement the dom interfaces for the classes that make up my tree (making it appear to be an XML document)? This way I could try and feed my duckish XML document to an XPathExpression.
- Should I just byte the bullet and implement my own XPath engine that will 'just work' on my classes?
- Should I instead just manually construct XML documents and pay the toString cost?
- Or is there some really easy way of parsing my binary files to XML that I have totally missed that is both fast to parse and fast to execute XPath queries on?

I also really don't want to waste my time by implementing the dom interfaces only to find out that XPathExpression will choke or that I have to also implement XPathExpression too.

I really do not want to write my own XPath engine.

Comment: Would it be possible to convert those binary files into XML files? that seems to be the easier way

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the DOM interfaces was the easy and mostly pain free solution. I was surprised to find that it worked! Turns out Java's XPath library doesn't care as long as you feed it something that implements the interfaces. You don't even need to implement most of the methods. You only need to implement (some of the) getters, everything else can just throw an unimplemented or read-only exception.

For those reading this in the future you should implement the complete interface and then use the methods to build the tree. The reason is that it is ugly to setup the sibling and parent relationships otherwise. You are going to have to write the code anyway, might as well put it in the right place.